# Can you apply "roughness" to a piece of a mesh?

Tags: textures, mesh, poisson

So I've used the program CloudCompare and its implementation of the Poisson Surface Reconstruction algorithm to create a water-tight mesh. 
There are no problems with the mesh, but I want the areas that were filled in using Poisson to appear equally as "rough" as the rest of the mesh. 
Due to the nature of the algorithm, any mesh created to fill in holes are smooth, making it look unnatural when compared to an area next to it that had points. 
Is there a way to somehow grab the "feel" or "roughness" of the surrounding area and apply it on the areas that were generated? 
I've looked into displacement maps and normal maps, but from what I've found that pertains to overlaying the map from a high-res model onto a low-res model.